# Insufficient authentication scopes - goggle appscript - getting project versions

Tags: google-apps-script, scopes

I am using the following code to get version information on my script file:

```
function getProjectVersionNumber(scriptId, theAccessTkn) {
  try {
    var allVersions, errMsg, highestVersion, options, payload, response, url;

    if (!scriptId) {
      //Logger.log('There was an error - No scriptID')
      //Error handling function
      throw new Error('There is no script ID for fnk getProjectVersionNumber');
    }

    if (!theAccessTkn) {
      theAccessTkn = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    }

    url = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + scriptId + "/versions";

    options = {
      "method": "GET",
      "muteHttpExceptions": true,
      "headers": {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + theAccessTkn
      }
    };

    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    //Logger.log('response : ' + JSON.stringify(response).slice(0,500));
    let rc = response.getResponseCode();
    let rccontext = response.getContentText();
    Logger.log("Response code %s, context returned %s",rc,rccontext);
    let responseJ = JSON.parse(response);//The response must be parsed into JSON even though it is an object

    if (typeof responseJ === 'object') {

      errMsg = responseJ.error;
      if (errMsg) {
        errMsg = errMsg.message;
        Logger.log(errMsg);
        return 'err' + errMsg;
      }
    }

    allVersions = responseJ.versions;//Get versions

    highestVersion = allVersions[0].versionNumber;
    //Logger.log("highestVersion: " + highestVersion)

    return highestVersion;
  } catch (e) {
    myErrorHandlingFunction_(e);
  }
}
function go () {
  var scriptID = ScriptApp.getScriptId();
  var   theAccessTkn = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  let l = getProjectVersionNumber(scriptID,theAccessTkn);
  Logger.log(l)
}
```

when I execute this, I get a 403 permission denied error:

```
Response code 403.0, context returned {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "google.apps.script.management.v1.ProjectsService.ListVersions",
          "service": "script.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In google console, I have verified that I have the Apps Script API enabled.

When I use the Google Workplace script playgound to execute this api, it works fine me. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.versions/list

Why won't this work in the script editor?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time when I get insufficient scope errors it tells me what I have to add and I add it and move on.

I modified your code down to the essentials and it ran ass follows:

```
function getProjectVersionNumber() {
    url = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + gobj.globals.scriptid + "/versions";
    options = {
      "method": "GET", "muteHttpExceptions": true, "headers": { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }
    };
    let res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    Logger.log(res.getContentText());
}
```

gobj.globals.scriptid is my global variable for my script id

I think one of these is the scope:

`"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp"`,
`"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.deployments"`

Comment: where do you add the scopes? in the appsscript.json file or somewhere else? @Cooper

I'm kind of struggling with that

Comment: with updated appsscript.json, still get the same results:

Comment: "oauthScopes": [
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp", 
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.deployments",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
        ]